# Set dropdown based on $scope match

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-select

I have a table that displays two columns using ng-repeat.

First column is a list of items pulled from one source.

Second column is a select element pulled from a second list.

What I want to do is automatically select an option in the dropdown, if it matches what is displayed in the left column.

I put together a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/raz1j9rt/1/

Here is my HTML:

```
<header>
    <title>myTittle</title>
</header>
<body ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myController'>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div>
            <form>
                <table class="table  table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <th>From File</th>
                        <th>Map To</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tr class="selector-row" ng-repeat="(key,value) in List1">
                        <td><span id="myspan">{{value}}</span>

                        </td>
                        <td style="padding:10px;">
                            <select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="data[value]" class="form-control">
                                <option ng-repeat="(key,value) in Match" value="{{value}}">{{value}}</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>{{ data }}</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is my JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.List1 = ['product1', 'product2', 'product3', 'product4', 'product5'];
    $scope.Match = ['product1', 'somethtingElse1', 'product3', 'somethingElse2', 'product5'];


}])
```

Not really sure where to start on this...

Comment: first, your syntax is all sorts of wrong here.  you have an array of strings, but you are using `ng-repeat` with `(key,value)`, which makes no sense, since these are not objects and do not have keys or values.  Secondly, since these dropdowns are in an ng-repeat, each one has it's own scope, and since you are using primitive strings, you will have prototype inheritance issues.

Comment: also worth mentioning, it's generally better to use `ng-options` rather than `ng-repeat` in a select.  All in all, this code needs a complete rewrite to be semantically correct before it can be set up to do what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks Claies. This is just a quick mock, as I'm actually pulling JSON objects for the lists.

Comment: I tried a couple quick combinations of `ng-select`, `ng-change`, etc., and I think that instead of expecting the `$scope.data` to be set by the dropdown, you probably should populate the `$scope.data` in the controller, and then allow the dropdown to change the value if it isn't the default.  this doesn't seem to be logic that can or should be achieved in the view.

Comment: Thanks, Claies. Appreciate the help. I'll try what dboskofic posted.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Claies point, here's a working fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/dboskovic/raz1j9rt/2/

Add this to your controller.

```
// setup default matches
angular.forEach($scope.List1, function(v){
    $scope.data[v] = $scope.Match.filter(function(d){
        if(d === v) return true;
        return false;
    })[0];
})
```

And then change your select to:

```
<select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="data[value]" class="form-control" ng-options="x for x in Match"></select>
```

Comment: thanks, dboskovic. I'll give that a try and will let you know how it went.